# How to change reference color to blue

Tags: color, citing, revtex

I downloaded a template from [Journal of Applied Physics - Scitation](http://publishing.aip.org/authors/preparing-your-manuscript).

You can see the template from this link http://publishing.aip.org/authors/preparing-your-manuscript

The problem is that the reference colour in this template is not blue, can you help me to change it to blue. I did several attempts but all of them did not work.

Here is the code that may help for solving:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[%
 reprint,%
%secnumarabic,%
 amssymb, amsmath,%
 aip,cha,%
%groupedaddress,%
%frontmatterverbose,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{docs}%
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\nofiles
\expandafter\ifx\csname package@font\endcsname\relax\else
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter\usepackage
 \expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter{\csname package@font\endcsname}%
\fi
\hyphenation{title}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: The site states "[t]he AIP Publishing Style will only work with REVTeX 4.1 and the latest version of `natbib`, `natbib8.3`." So I assume that your tagging this question `biblatex` was an oversight and you actually wanted `natbib`. Please make sure to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for this kind of question. (And link to the template explicitly, I found a download link on that site, but am not sure if it the right one). Plus, you might want to be more specific about what you mean by "reference colour": Is it the colour of citations or links?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean the colour of citation please. It is not blue and I don't know how to change.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the questions's MWE:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
```

Citation links are configured via option `citecolor`:

```
citecolor=blue
```

Or if all kind of links should be blue (since `hyperref` 2011-02-05 v6.82a):

```
allcolors=blue
```

Comment: Sorry, if I want to change the colour of the email how can I do it? Here is the code of email 


\email{AA@AA.AA.COM}

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi Also `hyperref` has a [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf): `urlcolor`.

Comment: I solved it by using allcolors=blue.

Comment: But if one only wants a certain section of a document to have colored references and links? Can this setting only be set globally?

Comment: @E.l4d3 The colors can also be changed via `\hypersetup` that can be called in local scope.