# Citations in color, but only the citations, not other in-document references

Tags: color, citing

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238105/192394) post shows how to color within-document links, and I am happy to have this in a document I am writing. My main motivation was to put long sequences of references in one color so my eyes know where the next sentence starts. Now, if I want to skip over a list of twelve author-year references, it is easy. However, this also puts other references in that color. I am okay with having other links within my PDF output so that I can go up a few pages back to an equation, for instance, but I do not want `\ref` to give text in color.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
```

How can I modify the linked syntax so that bibliography citations appear in color but only the bibliography citations? The link mentions using `citecolor = blue`, but that still leaves colors in my `\ref` references.

**EDIT**

Amazing: if I change the color, the old color remains for my `\ref` references.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}`...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To color only certain citation labels, you need to redefine `citecolor` in a local group

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
        
\begin{document}


{
\hypersetup{citecolor=SlateBlue2, citebordercolor=SlateBlue2, colorlinks=true}
\cite{westfahl:space,set,stdmodel,aksin,angenendt,baez/article,bertram,doody,matuz:doody,gillies,glashow,herrmann,kastenholz,murray}
}

\cite{westfahl:space,set,stdmodel,aksin,angenendt,baez/article,bertram,doody,matuz:doody,gillies,glashow,herrmann,kastenholz,murray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I copied that verbatim into TeXstudio and got the following in all black: `[westfahl:space; set; stdmodel; aksin; angenendt; baez/article; bertram;
doody; matuz:doody; gillies; glashow; herrmann; kastenholz; murray]
[westfahl:space; set; stdmodel; aksin; angenendt; baez/article; bertram;
doody; matuz:doody; gillies; glashow; herrmann; kastenholz; murray]`. What's going on?

Comment: Does TeXstudio show any errors/warnings (despite the warning in line 15)? Is your bib-file accessible for your document? Did you compile often enough such that the `.aux` file is written correctly? I get the expected output in Overleaf

Comment: @Dave. You must get `biblatex-examples.bib` from the following directory `%AppData%\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\bibtex\bib\biblatex`

Comment: I tried it with my own references, and they still show up in black. Thoughts?